# logic is correct but output is not

Tags: vb.net

It is a function that converts decimal into binary. It is not converting values to binary correctly. This gives `10101` for 19 instead of `10011`. How can it be corrected?

```
Function Binary(n As Integer)
    If n = 0 Or n = 1 Then
        Console.Write(n)
    Else
        Binary(n / 2)
        Console.Write(n Mod 2)
    End If
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim n As Integer
    Console.Write("Enter Number: ")
    n = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write(Binary(n))
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something that might drive you crazy because of how small it is, but the problem is with which division operator you use.

Doing it with `Binary(n / 2)` treats the integer as a double and passes 9.5 to Binary, while `Binary(n \ 2)` is the designated integer division operator. You can read more about Arithmetic Operators [on Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/arithmetic-operators).

Here's what I ran:

```
Module Module1

    Function Binary(n As Integer)
        If n = 0 Or n = 1 Then
            Console.Write(n)
        Else
            Binary(n \ 2)
            Console.Write(n Mod 2)
        End If
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim n As Integer
        Console.Write("Enter Number: ")
        n = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write(Binary(n))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output for 19: 10011

Comment: Thanks a Million :)